# Remove AD user from Security group using Python

Tags: python, active-directory, pywin32

I am trying to remove a user from a security group using Python and pywin32, but so far have not been successful. However I am able to add a user to a security group.

```
from win32com.client import GetObject

grp = GetObject("LDAP://CN=groupname,OU=groups,DC=blah,DC=local")

grp.Add("LDAP://CN=username,OU=users,DC=blah,DC=local") # successfully adds a user to the group

grp.Remove("LDAP://CN=username,OU=users,DC=blah,DC=local") # returns an error
```

The error is below:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "<COMObject LDAP://CN=groupname,OU=groups,DC=blah,DC=local>", line 2, in Remove
pywintypes.com_error: (-2147352567, 'Exception occurred.', (0, None, None, None,
 0, -2147024891), None)
```

I have also tried adding using GetObject to get the user and remove it that way, however I get the same error.

```
usr = GetObject("LDAP://CN=user,OU=users,DC=blah,DC=local")

grp.Remove(usr)
```

Any help would be much appreciated as I've hit a dead-end here.

EDIT

I have also now tried using Tim Golden's active_directory module to try and remove the group member.

```
import active_directory as ad

grp = ad.find_group("groupname")
usr = ad.find_user("username")

grp.remove(usr.path())
```

However this also doesn't work, and I encounter the below error.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Python33\lib\site-packages\active_directory.py", line 799, in __getat
tr__
    attr = getattr(self.com_object, name)
AttributeError: 'PyIADs' object has no attribute 'group'

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Python33\lib\site-packages\active_directory.py", line 802, in __getat
tr__
    attr = self.com_object.Get(name)
pywintypes.com_error: (-2147463155, 'OLE error 0x8000500d', (0, 'Active Director
y', 'The directory property cannot be found in the cache.\r\n', None, 0, -214746
3155), None)

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "C:\Python33\lib\site-packages\active_directory.py", line 1081, in remove

    self.group.Remove(dn)
  File "C:\Python33\lib\site-packages\active_directory.py", line 804, in __getat
tr__
    raise AttributeError
AttributeError
```

EDIT

Wherby suggested that I change to Python 2.7 and give that a go. I have just tried this:

```
import active_directory as ad

user = ad.find_user("username")
group = ad.find_group("groupname")

group.remove(user.path())
```

... but I'm still getting an error

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "<COMObject LDAP://CN=groupname,OU=groups,DC=blah,DC=local>", line 2, in remove
pywintypes.com_error: (-2147352567, 'Exception occurred.', (0, None, None, None,
 0, -2147024891), None)
```

The user and group are definitely found correctly, as I can print their LDAP paths using `print user.path()` and `print group.path()`

Are there any other active directory libraries for Python 3.3 that anyone can recommend?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, I've gone and figured out I was being a bit of a muppet. The account I was logged in to didn't have the permissions to delete from AD groups. When I logged in as the network admin account it worked like a charm.

The final code:

```
from win32com.client import GetObject

group = GetObject("LDAP://CN=groupname,OU=Groups,DC=blah,DC=local")

group.Remove("LDAP://CN=username,OU=Users,DC=blah,DC=local")
```

Answer (score 0):

From

```
    Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Python33\lib\site-packages\active_directory.py", line 799, in __getat
tr__
    attr = getattr(self.com_object, name)
AttributeError: 'PyIADs' object has no attribute 'group'
```

The error indicate you are using not existed "group name", the function find_group required anexisted group name, but you give not existed name.
You should double check "Tim Golden's active_directory module" 's manual.

For

```
usr = GetObject("LDAP://CN=user,OU=users,DC=blah,DC=local")

grp.Remove(usr)
```

I suggest you add "print user" to see if the user really get.

Comment: What do you mean by an existed group name? The group definitely exists and when I get it with find_group I am able to print it. I am also able to print the user.

Comment: You mean in ad you have a group named "group", and also have a user which name is "username"?

Comment: No... those were examples where I replaced the actual name of the group/user because they're irrelevant.

Comment: Having said that, the AttributeError that is raised hasn't been edited by me at all. The error literally states: "'PyIADs' object has no attribute 'group'."

Comment: I notice that you are using python 3.3, and latest active_directory module is build by 2007. I suggest you change to use python 2.7.  On my machine, the remove function works for python 2.7.

Comment: I'll give that a go, however I am not familiar with Python 2.7. Do you know of a different active directory module I could use that is compatible with Python 3.3?